# Hand ball and free-kicks

Tags: rules, football

If I kick the ball into the opponents hand, do I get a free kick due to hand-ball by the opponent? Can I keep on doing this until I'm right in front of their net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, no.

A player only commits a handling offence if they **deliberately** handle the ball (this excludes the goalkeeper handling the ball within their own penalty area). This includes any part of their arm as well, and not just their hand.<sup>*</sup>

Generally, if a player's arm is in a natural position (usually down by their side, or reasonably raised when jumping for balance), and they do not have a reasonable amount of time to move it out of the way, no offence has occurred, as they have not deliberately handled it.<sup>*</sup>

If their arm is in an unnatural position (outstretched), it's most likely there to make them bigger, and hence to deliberately handle the ball. If a player has their arms out wide for no good reason, and you kick the ball into them, then yes, they have committed a handling offence.

As this is a relatively rare occurrence, most of the time, when you kick the ball into a player's arm/hand, particularly from a short distance, no offence has occurred.

<sub>* - p. 119, [2014/15 FIFA Laws of The Game](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/footballdevelopment/technicalsupport/refereeing/laws-of-the-game/index.html)</sub>

Comment: Nice reference :)

Answer (score 1):

In determining whether or not a player deliberately handled the ball, the referee has several considerations: Movement of the hand towards the ball (not the ball towards the hand); Distance between the opponent and the ball (unexpected ball); Touching the ball with an object held in the hand (clothing, shinguard, etc.) counts as an infringement (considered an extension of the hand).

Comment: Say I have 100% accuracy and my opponents always place their hands at their side. Then theoretically, I can give them infinite fouls by kicking the ball to their hand all game long?

Comment: This answer could be improved by clearly stating the rule (ie. deliberately handles the ball) in the body of the answer.